# Where can I get detailed understanding of mysql-server's codebase?

Tags: mysql, github, open-source

Is there any resource of how mysql's source code (https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server) works?
Any flow diagrams related to code's folders and files.

Comment: Have you checked the official docs?

Comment: Where are the official docs?
The information of mysql side is quite insufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official docs includes a section called [MySQL Internals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/).  There are sections included about navigating the source tree and what is where.

If you can look past his blatant towing of the company line (e.g. his apparent claims that the "real" MySQL will always be better and more awesome than MariaDB or Percona, because... Oracle!) and that he seems to imply that if you make any change to the source, you have to give those changes to Oracle and should probably send them a bunch of money, too... then there is some good material to be found in a book called [Expert MySQL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00ACC6ANM), which includes a decent low-level view of how it works and code snippets walking you through some source code tweaks to add new functionality.

But, there is a large amount of in-line documentation embedded in the code itself.

Answer (score -2):

how "source code works"? it is in sources i guess

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B

https://www.google.ru/search?q=flow+diagram+mysql&newwindow=1&safe=off&espv=2&biw=1600&bih=852&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CBsQsARqFQoTCPXHzsTD88cCFcYlcgodYHME-w&dpr=0.9#imgrc=MrlmbXUK6VPJjM%3A

Comment: I am asking about the detailed architecture of mysql's source code!